# Crystal Report not running - Database Logon - Prompt

Tags: database, crystal-reports, business-objects, crystal-reports-2010

I am getting this report not running,  going to the database. I have to login to get it to work and it will work, but I don't want the users to have to log in. I have checked the connection.  It connects from the boxes to the database in ODBC.  This report completely works before it is promoted.  It is promoted from 4.1 to 4.1.  Other reports using the same database are working, but others are still giving this prompt as well. Most are working, and they are using the same connection in BOE. This exact report works in Dev. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You mean report is prompting for database logon in BOE for users and you dont want that? Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I fixed it by reinstalling the native client

Answer (score 0):

In BOE when you upload the report, Right click and go to database configuration there select appropriate driver and provide database login credentials.

After providing the details select the radio button that will tell **use the same database details every time**... probably 3rd option and click on save.

Comment: It was the same in Dev and Prod though.  It wasn't prompting in Dev